# How to generate a Panorama image (360-degree image) programmatically for a given GLTF file?

Tags: gltf

How can I generate a Panorama image (360-degree image) programmatically (preferably Java) from a given GLTF file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's in the glTF file: is it just one model, or is there a whole scene that a panoramic camera can be placed inside?  In other words, does this need to work for any glTF file?  I can't picture how one would make an entire panorama from one 3D model, unless the camera could fit inside the model someplace (which is not typical, but for certain models would be fine).

Comment: Hi @emackey, assume that the camera is placed inside the scene.